# Somando Quantidade de Entrada por mês e cliente

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

Oi, não estou conseguindo somar a quantidade de entrada de produtos por cliente e por mês. Alguém consegue me ajudar com alguma dica? Estou tendo o seguinte resultado:

```
MÊS Quantidade
1   95
1   55
2   90
3   140
3   40
3   95
3   40
```

**Correto seria:**

```
MÊS Quantidade
1   150
2   90
3   140
3   315
```

Query:

```
SELECT MONTH(TMOV.DATASAIDA) AS MES, SUM(TITMMOV.QUANTIDADE) AS QUANTIDADE
FROM 
(TPRD INNER JOIN (FCFO INNER JOIN (TMOV INNER JOIN TITMMOV ON (TMOV.IDMOV = TITMMOV.IDMOV) 
AND (TMOV.CODCOLIGADA = TITMMOV.CODCOLIGADA)) ON FCFO.CODCFO = TMOV.CODCFO) ON (TPRD.IDPRD = TITMMOV.IDPRD) 
AND (TPRD.CODCOLIGADA = TMOV.CODCOLIGADA)) INNER JOIN TMOVCOMPL ON (TMOV.IDMOV = TMOVCOMPL.IDMOV) 
AND (TMOV.CODCOLIGADA = TMOVCOMPL.CODCOLIGADA)
WHERE TITMMOV.CODCOLIGADA Between '1' And '2' AND TMOV.CODTMV='1.1.70'
AND TMOV.CODCFO ='003582' AND CIDADECOLETA = '00051'
AND TMOV.DATASAIDA >= '2021-01-01 00:00:00'
AND TPRD.CODIGOPRD >= '04.001.0001' AND TPRD.CODIGOPRD <= '04.003.9999' 
And TPRD.CODIGOPRD > '03.999.9999' AND TMOV.STATUS <> 'C'
GROUP BY TITMMOV.QUANTIDADE, TMOV.DATASAIDA
```

Comment: tem que agrupar pelo mesmo critério do select: `group by MONTH(TMOV.DATASAIDA)`, quantidade já é agrupada no `SUM`, não precisa aparecer no group by

Answer (score 0):

Tarde, o erro está no Group BY, alterar para GROUP BY  MONTH(TMOV.DATASAIDA)

```
SELECT MONTH(TMOV.DATASAIDA) AS MES, SUM(TITMMOV.QUANTIDADE) AS QUANTIDADE
FROM DBO.TMOV 
INNER JOIN DBO.TITMMOV ON (TMOV.CODCOLIGADA = TITMMOV.CODCOLIGADA AND TMOV.IDMOV = TITMMOV.IDMOV)
INNER JOIN DBO.TPRODUTO ON (TPRODUTO.CODCOLPRD = TITMMOV.CODCOLIGADA AND TPRODUTO.IDPRD = TITMMOV.IDPRD) 
WHERE TMOV.CODCOLIGADA Between '1' And '2' AND TMOV.CODTMV='1.1.70'
AND TMOV.CODCFO ='003582' 
--> QUAL TABELA 
AND CIDADECOLETA = '00051'
AND TMOV.DATASAIDA >= '2021-01-01 00:00:00'
AND TPRODUTO.CODIGOPRD >= '04.001.0001' 
AND TPRODUTO.CODIGOPRD <= '04.003.9999' 
And TPRODUTO.CODIGOPRD > '03.999.9999' AND TMOV.STATUS <> 'C'
GROUP BY  MONTH(TMOV.DATASAIDA)
```

porém, sua consulta esta fazendo JOIN em tabelas não utilizadas, logo para uma melhor performance deves verificar!